# How can I use Quantum Shanon Decomposition for any $N \times N$ matrix?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-algorithms

I have a non-unitary and non-hermitian matrix of $16\times16$. I have used singular value decomposition to break that matrix into three matrices i.e. $A = UDV$, Where $U$ and $V$ are unitary but still non-hermitian, while D is the diagonal matrix. Now, I want to implement this matrix on a quantum circuit in qiskit in form of universal set of gates.

Here, I have came across the term Shannon decomposition and then quantum Shannon decomposition. Currently, I am unable to grasp the concept and cannot find the basic mathematics in matrix form that governs the decomposition process. I know it must be simple but stuck here.

If there are relevant books on the topic as research papers make it complex. Also, if there is a qiskit code that can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the matrix that you are trying to implement is non-unitary, the quantum Shannon decomposition (originally introduced in [this paper by Shende, Bullock and Markov](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0406176)) is not a useful approach. To implement a non-unitary operation on a quantum computer, one must embed it in a larger unitary operation in a process that goes by the name of *block encoding*, as discussed in [this previous question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/29732/doing-non-unitary-operations-on-quantum-computer). For a more in-depth pedagogical introduction, I would recommend [Lin Lin's lecture notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.08309) (Chapter 6, in particular). Finally, since your matrix is not even Hermitian, you should consider quantum singular value transformation (see Chapter 8 of the aforementioned lecture notes or [this PRX Quantum tutorial](https://journals.aps.org/prxquantum/abstract/10.1103/PRXQuantum.2.040203)).

Comment: Thankyou for the help, it really cleared my concepts on the topic from the [Lin Lin's lecture notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.08309). Additionally, I used Singular value decomposition in Mathematica to decompose the matrices into unitary and diagonal matrix. Further, I used the code from [quantum-decomp](https://github.com/fedimser/quantum_decomp/blob/master/quantum_decomp/quantum_decomp_main.py) to form the quantum circuit in qiskit. Currently, I want to test this circuit, if it gives correct results or not. I will share if it works.